# What is the tau parameter in the Black-Litterman model?

Tags: black-litterman

Could someone please provide me with a clear and concise definition of the $\tau$ parameter in the Black-Litterman model? It seems one is rather hard to come by. I understand it to be the 'weight on views', but this is a little vague.

Comment: I collected some papers, possibly you already know them. Are they helpful? Do you want a more specific insight?

Comment: I am aware of Meucci's paper - but the other ones not at all. The step-by-step guide looks promising though, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is one generally accepted method and a number of papers are written on this issue.

The [Black-Litterman Approach: Original Model and Extensions (2008)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1117574) by Meucci has an overview and I believe is generally useful to learn more. It suggests using $\tau = \frac{1}{T}$ but notes more complicated approaches exist. [A demystification of the Black–Litterman model: Managing quantitative and traditional portfolio construction (2000)](http://www.palgrave-journals.com/jam/journal/v1/n2/abs/2240011a.html) by Satchell Scowcroft "propose an ingenious model where $\tau$ is stochastic, but extra parameters need to be calibrated." (Meucci). [The Black Litterman Model: A Detailed Exploration](http://www.master272.com/finance/BL/JWalters_Black-Litterman.pdf) (2008) by Walters gives another overview. Of course, you can't miss Idzoreks A [step-by-step guide to the Black-Litterman model (2004)](http://www.indiceperu.com/lecturas/paper13.pdf). This [blog](http://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/tauidzorek/) might also be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

Jay Walter's Paper on "The Factor Tau in the Black-Litterman Model"
http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1701467 is also useful to review

Answer (score 1):

There is also http://www.blacklitterman.org/ Where you can find an implementation under Excel and Matlab of the Model.